# Two Uncountable Sets Making a Infinitely Countable Set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following: $A$ and $B$ are uncountable sets, what is a infinite countable result from $A \oplus B$ where $\oplus$ is the symmetric difference.

**My solution**:

Define $A= \mathbb Q \cup \mathbb R$ and $B= \mathbb R$

Thus, $A \oplus B = \mathbb Q$ which is countably infinite.

As you can tell, I am having a hard time justify my answers and the idea of what symmetric difference does with certain steps. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your solution is a correct one (more or less).  You really need $A$ to be the disjoint union of $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$.  So I'd frame it as $A= \{ (x, 0) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid a \in \Bbb Q \} \cup B$, where $B= \{ (0, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \}$.  What problem are you having?

Comment: That doesn’t work, because $\Bbb Q\cup\Bbb R=\Bbb R$, so $A\oplus B=\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R=\varnothing$. Try $A=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Comment: So $A= \mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q$ is saying everything in A is every real number besides the the rationals, so $A \oplus B$ would be just $\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $A\oplus B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$.

If you want $A$ and $B$ to be uncountable, but $A\oplus B$ to be countable, that means that $A\cup B$ is "almost" $A\cap B$. But if $A=B$, we get $A\oplus B=\varnothing$, which is not infinite enough.

What you can do is reverse engineer this. Start with $C=A\oplus B$, which is countably infinite, for example $\Bbb N$, and then pick your favourite uncountable set $X$, and let $A=X$ and $B=X\cup C$. Or, split $C$ into two parts, $C_0$ and $C_1$, and let $A=C_0\cup X$ and $B=C_1\cup X$.

Comment: So I kind of did this but reversed $A$ and $B$. So say I pick $A=[0,5]$ and $B = [6,7] \cup \mathbb N$ would the result of $A \oplus B = \mathbb N$?

Comment: You have the formula. Why ask me?